# Batch: surpress output of REG

Tags: batch-file, registry

I want to surpress the output of a REG Delete command when it succeeds. ATM I have this:

```
IF %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE% == x86 
               REG delete HKLM\Software\XXX /v ConfiguratorPath /f 2>nul
```

It doesn´t put out anything when i get an error...but if it succeeds, it prints out some lines..

how can I fix that? please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IF %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE% == x86 (
      REG delete HKLM\Software\XXX /v ConfiguratorPath /f >nul 2>&1
)
```